# How to Configure the Elasticsearch with fuzzy search

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, devops

I have requirement where I need to install the elasticsearch where they want to use it for doing fuzzy search.

How do I configure it and installed on the Linux box

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You no need any other configuration for using Elastic fuzzy search. What you care is query string.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Answer (score 1):

To install Elasticsearch in Linux, you can refer to this official [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html)

There can be several types of fuzzy searches according to your use case -

**1. You can use `match` with `fuzziness` parameter**

**2. You can use fuzzy query**

---

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "breadsticks"
}
```

**Search Query using Match Query:**

Searching for `breastiks` instead of `breadsticks`

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "name":{
        "query":"breadstiks",
        "fuzziness":"auto"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66962659",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.25891387,
        "_source": {
          "name": "breadsticks"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**You can set the [fuzziness value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) according to your use case**

---

**Search Query using Fuzzy query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "name": {
        "value": "breadstiks"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @chinnam did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)